# When invoking `call` in redux-saga, is the async action scheduled to be run?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I see a saga:

```
export function* mySaga({ username, password }) {
    yield call(login, username, password);
}
```

Does the invocation of this saga schedule the `login` function to be called by the saga middleware or does it, instead, only create and configure an effect that is returned and used by the middleware to schedule the call to `login`?

Answer (score 0):

[It merely configures an effect to be used by the middleware](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html).

> Put another way, the Generator will yield plain Objects containing instructions, and the redux-saga middleware will take care of executing those instructions and giving back the result of their execution to the Generator.